# SOQL query to get cases with case comment for open(processing) cases

Tags: soql

here is our requirement we need to get cases with case comments where case comment done 3 days ago for open cases(we are considering Processing, work in progress and pending closure cases as open cases). All this is to track pending(open) cases and we sent this to supporting team manager. In the following query we are getting all pending(open) cases but the problem is, the query showing cases worked on today (think child query is not running correctly, any suggestion?.

**SOQL QUERY:**

```
Select Id, Main_issue__c, Sub_issue__c, CaseNumber, status, Owner.Name,
   (Select Id, CreatedBy.name, LastModifiedDate, CreatedDate 
    From CaseComments 
    WHERE CreatedDate >= LAST_N_DAYS:3 
    ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) 
From Case 
WHERE Status IN('Processing','Work in progress','Pending Closure') 
ORDER BY Owner.Name
```

Comment: Is the request to get case comments that were made exactly three days ago or to get the most recent comment that was posted greater than three days ago?

In addition, if you want only open cases, you can change your WHERE clause in the parent query to IsClosed = FALSE, but only if there are no other statuses being excluded that are "open".

Comment: The request is to get case comments that were made exactly 3 days ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to include a sub-query in the filter clause. The following query returns cases that have one of those three status values and do not have a case comment for at least three days.

```
Select Id, Main_issue__c, Sub_issue__c, CaseNumber, status, Owner.Name
From Case 
WHERE Status IN('Processing','Work in progress','Pending Closure') 
      AND Id NOT IN (SELECT ParentId FROM CaseComment WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:3)
ORDER BY Owner.Name
```

Feel free to adjust this as you desire.

Comment: Thank you!! for the solution and sorry for the delay in my response.